# Force ImportXml google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Since 2 weeks the trick to force XMLImport with a time valude within URL is no longer working.

=IMPORTXML("http://myURL.com"&"&"&TEXT(NOW(),"yyyymmddHHmm","//tr")

URL reconstruction seems to be unsupported now or block by google. :( I've tried, I've tried another trick but in vain...

The documentation was useful if you import live data into Google Docs spreadsheets using the importdata function and you want to force a refresh at a certain interval but it doesn't work right now...

https://gist.github.com/jaygooby/9932518

Any idea to overpass this limitation. Many thanks in advance.

Sébastien

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by creating a function and force the update in a define cell :

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B150').setValue("myurl?" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

Cheers